# How to avoid gesture overlap when using DrawerLayout?

Tags: android

I have a layout, which can be dragged from the right side of the screen.

```
@Bind(R.id.left_drawer_layout)
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

 @OnClick(R.id.left_drawer)
    void onLeftDrawer() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            closeLeftDrawer();
        } else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
```

Inside this drawer I have a WebView which displays some content that are huge in size, compared to webView borders. That's why I need to scroll it in any direction:

```
up
down
left
right
```

The two last gestures are overwriten by DrawerLayout while it is some levels upper than the webView.

How can I overwrite the behavoir of my  WebView so it can be draggable(scrollable) in any direction and not affect my DrawerLayout?

Comment: did you set scrollbars to your webview?

Comment: yes, I have them. I can scroll up and down and right if the drawer is completely opened.

Comment: did you tried to setOnTouchListener to view and return always true?

Comment: not sure how this can help me. I think I need to capture motion and then move only webView

Comment: If you know, how to touches handled in android, this could help you. In short, when you touches the view, android handle it, then if touchEvent return false go to parent view and try to handle touch event on it, or if return true, finishingm the interaction, Since web view is a child of drawer layout in your case, thus, you could block touch to drawer, but proceed touch for webview. It just a suggestion.

Comment: Added a TouchListener but it blocked all actins applied to webView. return false; make this listener work as default. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to return true, not false. But if it not works, try to extend web view and override working with touches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120430/discussion-between-alexey-polusov-and-michael-spitsin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty much simple: Lock DrawerLayout while we are touching our WebView:

```
 webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getDrawerLayout()
                        .setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getDrawerLayout()
                        .setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```